# Is it possible to put some Buttons in a Linear or Relative Layout in variable rows?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to have only 1 layout. In this layout there is a linear or relative layout which I have put some buttons in it.

If the device is small, my buttons does not fit to the LinearLayout and some of them go outside the activity and are not visible like this:

[image]

I want to do something that when the device screen is small, the extra buttons go to the second line automatically like this:

[image]

Is it possible? Is there any properties in LinearLayout or RelativeLayout that satisfy this need?

Comment: it looks like a GridLayout to me, more than a Linear/Relative layout. It is in the support library. Check if it suits your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option for you is to try [android-flowlayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) library

Answer (score 1):

a better approach would be building a unique layout for each device's screen size to make sure that every thing is in the right place.

you just need to add the fallowing folders in your resources:

```
layout-small
layout
layout-large
layout-xlarge
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp
```

and begin designing for each one of those screens.
for more info: [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I know. I do not want to create multiple layouts

Answer (score 0):

Use GridView . And add Button into GridView .

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the Screensize of each device at run time with something like this

`

```
int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
//              & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
//
//      switch (screenSize) {
//      case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
//          Do something for Large Screens
//          break;
//      case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
//          Do something for Normal Screens
//          break;
//      case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
//          Do something for XLarge Screens
//          break;
//      case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_UNDEFINED:
//          Do something for Undefined Screens like televisions or something
//          break;
//      case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
//          Do something for small Screens
//          break;
//      default:
//          Do something for default Screens if all else fails
//      }`
```

Forgive the comments, but that is one way of implementing different views with different requirements in your activity at run time. Also note that you could simply do something like

```
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:maxLength="20"
```

To force the Textview to always be one line or maxLines or length of 20, take your pick